# express route infinitely spins in browser

Tags: node.js, express

While making a simple server and trying to test the response from a dummy route, when I run it in chrome the browser infinitely spins and doesn't load the page.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParse = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const index = express();

// log formatter
index.use(morgan('combine'));
index.use(bodyParse.json);
index.use(cors());

index.get('/status', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        message: 'herrrooo'
    })
});

index.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: What URL are you loading in the browser?

Comment: localhost:5000/status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
index.use(bodyParse.json);
```

to this:

```
index.use(bodyParse.json());
```

You were not passing the right middleware function so express got stuck when it got to that middleware because the middleware never called `next()` to continue the request processing to the next step.

Example [here in the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples).